ETL from internal google sites to bigquery
I'm working on internal google sites to host all the product, projects & customer related content for my company to avail accessibility for sales & support teams.
- The data is hosted as per different regions for all the customers - each with their own subpage.
- All the pages are based on one template. We're talking about 1500-3000 such pages.
- Certain data on the pages, is rendered via html embed feature, where I've defined constants to populate the html tables.
- The data in these tables will keep changing as per future iterations. eg, when a customer's spoc details change, the team member will update the same in the site page.
What I couldn't find a working way to achieve is:
- Export the data from site pages to google bigquery (ETL Pipeline)

Sample code that needs to be extracted from iframe:
<body>
    <script>
        // Define values for heading1 section in the constant
        const heading1 = {
            clientName: "<clientName>",             //values
            clientType: "<clientType>",
            goLiveDate: "<goLiveDate>",
            product: "<product>",
        };

        // Define values for heading2 section
        const heading2 = [
            "<value1>", 
            "<value2>", 
            "<value3>", 
        ];
    </script>


I've found multiple forums, blogs & video tutorials regarding integrating Analytical data from bigquery to sites but not the other way around, which brings me here seeking the help.
It'd be great if any advice in this regard
[google-bigquery] [google-sites]
Tried appscripts to export in a sheet and than create an ETL, but export to sheet has it's own set of problems.

Please clarify, is the custom content in an iframe? Is the content from the iframe what you want? And do you want to save the whole iframe’s HTML content to a single field in BigQuery? Or the Site content without the iframe, as HTML? And what identifies the content as belonging to a user? Is there some unique key or field? A minimum reproducible example would help, even with dummy code.

@mjruttenberg - yes, the custom code is in an iframe and only the data from constants in the iframe is required.
In the beginning of html code for the iframe- the above script is defined with the constants as shown below:
sample code for reference:


There's no direct API or built-in export functionality for the content within the pages themselves, especially if it's rendered within HTML embed gadgets.
Instead of embedding HTML tables directly, store your data in Google Sheets. Use Apps Script to dynamically pull this data into your Google Sites pages. Embed your data as JSON within  tags on your pages. You can then use an Apps Script web app to crawl your Sites pages, parse the JSON, and send it to BigQuery.
